# R rounding time column without changing the rest of data set

Tags: r, date-formatting

I want to round the time in Date column to the nearest hour, but I do not want to touch any other column.

data_VOC_B:

```
    structure(list(Date = structure(list(sec = c(0, 0), min = c(24L, 
29L), hour = 8:9, mday = c(13L, 13L), mon = c(5L, 5L), year = c(-1887L, 
-1887L), wday = c(4L, 4L), yday = c(163L, 163L), isdst = c(0L, 
0L), zone = c("LMT", "LMT"), gmtoff = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_
)), .Names = c("sec", "min", "hour", "mday", "mon", "year", "wday", 
"yday", "isdst", "zone", "gmtoff"), class = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt"
)), ethane = structure(1:2, .Label = c("7.7", "9.5"), class = "factor"), 
    propane = structure(1:2, .Label = c("3", "3.3"), class = "factor"), 
    n.butane = structure(1:2, .Label = c("1.2", "2.3"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Date", 
"ethane", "propane", "n.butane"), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")
>
```

Date format: "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"

I tried several ways but I lose other columns, data points are replaced with NA. 
What is your suggestions?

Thank you,

Comment: `lubridate::round_date(data_VOC_B$Date, unit = "hour")`

Comment: @d.b I lose the other columns again when I run this code, do you have a suggestion?

Comment: Assign the output to the specific column you want to change and other columns will be fine. `data_VOC_B$Date = lubridate::round_date(data_VOC_B$Date, unit = "hour")`